# NullpointerException on loading xlsx file using Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi, openxml-sdk, xlsx

Am tryng to read a file using Apache POI 3.8 in mac osx environment, which is created in Windows using Open XML SDK 2.0 for Microsoft Office, am getting null pointer exception as it is unable to load the xlsx file. Below is the stack trace. I am able to open the file and view it.

The same code works for the files that I create in mac os env.  If i open and save the file before processing, am not having any issue. Note : The File size increases after saving it. Is it issue with file being generated in .net and being processed in mac osx environment.

Any clues why am i getting below error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.onDocumentRead(XSSFWorkbook.java:253)
        at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:159)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:183)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:73)
```

The class looks like below, with utility methods, did not copy the entire class. but this happens at line `wb = new XSSFWorkbook(bis)` while creating the workbook. I tried couple of options like `WorkbookFactory.create(bis)` instead of `XSSFWorkbook`, but the error remains same, issue is mainly with the file content.

```
public class XLSXReader {

    private BufferedInputStream bis;
    private boolean hasNext = true;
    int skipLines;

    private boolean linesSkiped;

    //   The default line to start reading.
    public static final int DEFAULT_SKIP_LINES = 0;

    private XSSFWorkbook wb =null;
    private XSSFSheet sheet=null;
    private int noOfCols;

    public XLSXReader(InputStream is){
        bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        this.noOfCols=0; 
        try {
            wb = new XSSFWorkbook(bis); 
            sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

// with basic utility methods ....
}
```

Comment: That excerpt of the stacktrace doesn't show what/where in your code the error was provoked.  Isn't there any mention of your code in the stacktrace, and if yes, could you show the code?

Comment: sorry, updated with details. pl. let me know if you need any other details.

Comment: If you open the file in excel, and do a save-as, does that fix the file so that POI can read it?

Comment: yes, it fixes the problem, but, we should be able to read it without opening and saving the file. Am not sure how to resolve this or why is it happening.

Comment: Are you skipping the styles table in your file? The exception line number seems to indicate that no styles table was there, and all normal .xlsx files should have one, is yours not with the way you're creating it?

Comment: That might be the issue, I receive a encrypted file xlsx file, I decrypt it to have the data in to a new .xlsx file. When i debugged the poi source code, it was failing at 'stylesSource.setTheme(theme);'. Can you let me know what should be done to add the styles table when creating the .xlsx file.

Comment: I was able to fix the issue once the client add styles.xml to xlsx generated using open xml sdk for .net. Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I think, your missing the `class path` problem. Try as below.
Make sure that `properties` directry must be in the `class path`.
Put your doucments file in these folder.

```
public class WorkBookReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            InputStream inp = new FileInputStream("properties/workbook.xls");
            Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);
            Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
            Row row = sheet.getRow(2);
            Cell cell = row.getCell(3);
            if (cell == null)
                cell = row.createCell(5);
            cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
            cell.setCellValue("Hello!");

            // Write the output to a file
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("properties/workbook.xls");
            wb.write(fileOut);
            fileOut.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it,it did not work. The program is able to find the file as it was not throwing FileNotFoundException and i can see number of bytes available, but it is unable to accept the format of the file.